# Get the full name of the migration file in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model, migration

how can I get the full name of the migration file in Laravel.
I need to migrate some migration files Instead of all files.
but I have problem to get time of the migration file like this file :

`database\migrations\`
**2014_10_12_000000**
`_create_users_table.php`

what is the way to do this ?

Comment: What do you mean with _"I have a problem to get time of migration file"_ ?

Comment: for example I have this migration file : 
2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php

I want to migrate the specific file .

if I want to do this out of the terminal ,  I need to have full name of migration file.

how can I get this full name in laravel?

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain what your are trying to do, why you're trying to do it and why you think getting the migration files manually will help solve your problem

Comment: I am dynamically starting to create tables in the project with the command line, and because I need some files later, I will migrate them later.

Answer (score 0):

we must use `File` Helper function in laravel to get all file names in special path , like this :

```
$filesName = \File::files(base_path().'\database\migrations\\');
    $arr = [];
    foreach ($filesName as $file) {
        $ex = explode("\\"  , $file);
        array_push($arr , $ex[count($ex) - 1]);
    }
return $arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this...

My helper

```
if(!function_exists('getFileName')){
    function getFileName($keyWord,$basePath='database\migrations',$fileBegin='_create_',$fileEnd='_table.php'){
        $path = base_path($basePath);
        $files = scandir($path);
        foreach($files as $file){
            if(strpos($file,$fileBegin.$keyWord.$fileEnd)){
                return $file;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My controller

```
dd(file_exists(base_path('database\migrations\\'.getFileName($model))),getFileName($model));
```

return

```
true
"2022_01_19_134622_create_songs_table.php"
```